# Notepad++ how to open a file on Windows that contains data that contains CRLF?

Tags: notepad++, newline, display

First of all I've read everything I can find on how to get Notepad++ to do this, but so far I haven't found an answer.

In Notepad++ on Windows I am trying to open a pipe-delimited text file (.txt) - but one of the fields in each line *can* contain CRLF.  Right now, Notepad++ thinks every CRLF is an end-of-line character...which make the lines displayed in Notepad++ look odd as they bump down or roll over to the next line when the field contains CRLF...WHEN THEY SHOULDN'T.

Is it possible to adjust Notepad++ to recognize the actual CRLF end-of-line characters, while leaving the CRLF characters that are present in the text itself alone?  TIA.

Comment: Short answer: No. How could you recognize a `CRLF` from another one?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but, it is easilly possible to replace all unwanted `CRLF` by a space (for example). You should post sample text and expected result (not an image, please).

Answer (score 0):

Peter Jones helped answer my question on the Notepad++ Community forum

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23244/open-a-pipe-delimited-text-file-on-windows-where-one-field-may-contain-crlf

I ended up doing a Find and Replace - in this pipe-delimited file, every new line **should** start with a left brace "{", so my replace was based on CRLF that is NOT followed by left brace.

Note that this actually **changes** the data, so I simply do this Find and Replace so that I can see the data properly --- I do NOT actually save this changed data.

HTH.